# Connect to Sharepoint URL without promt using Userid and password "Connect-PnPOnline" using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Connect to Sharepoint URL without promt using Userid and password "Connect-PnPOnline" using powershell

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $URL  -Credentials $Cred

Answer (score 0):

$username = "USERNAME"

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "PASSWORD" -AsPlainText -Force

$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($username, $password)

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $UrlOfSharepoint -Credentials $psCred